# How to measure time with time/times comand

Tags: unix, time

I have a scrip with a `while`. On that while i would like to measure the time that the content of it takes to run, in miliseconds, something like this:

```
while condition;
do
    #begin measure time at begining
    instructions
    #end measure time at end
    echo "$end-$begin"
done
```

I can't use `date +%s.%N` because my machine doesnt have it, so i need to use either `time` or `times` comand. Any idea how to?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the time command you can run the `instructions` part in a subshell:

!#/bin/bash

```
while condition;
do
    time $(
    instruction1
    instruction2
    )
done
```

You just have to parse the output of `time` afterwards. Working example:

```
mtak@rubiks:~$ time $(
> sleep 2
> sleep 3
> )

real    0m5,004s
user    0m0,000s
sys 0m0,000s
mtak@rubiks:~$
```

Comment: not sure that would work for my particular problem. My while is waiting for data form the serial port with `while read....`What i want to know i sthe time elapsed between every incoming data, so your approach is not valid in this particular matter :/

Comment: I agree it isn't, that's why it's helpful to make a good question (https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)